# hide Wordpress 3.1 admin menu

Tags: admin-bar

I just updated one of my blogs to the new wordpress 3.1 and i need to hide the admin menu that shows up on top of the pages. How do i disable it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the simplest way. install showhide-adminbar. then all subscriber won't see the adminbar even they set to show it in viewing site.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/showhide-adminbar/

Answer (score 8):

Go to Dashboard > Your Profile > Show Admin Bar and uncheck "when viewing site"

Comment: Can it be turned off globally? I don't want new subscribers to get the bar.

Comment: @wyrfel - I found this. Add `remove_action( 'init', 'wp_admin_bar_init' );` to your `functions.php`

Comment: +1 - Been holding onto that one liner since i read about the admin bar going into 3.1, i've hated the damn thing since i saw it appear on wordpress.com blogs.

Comment: Cool thanks, I need to disable it for all new users on a site where i'm using the p2 (twitter style theme)

Comment: Actually it turns out you shouldn't remove the init action to get rid of the admin bar (a filter on `show_admin_bar` is the correct way to do it).

Answer (score 6):

This would hide the Admin Bar for all users except Administrators. Add at end of `functions.php`:

```
function my_function_admin_bar($content) {
    return ( current_user_can("administrator") ) ? $content : false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
// Disable Admin Bar for all users
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

// Remove Admin Bar Options from all users' Profile page
add_action('admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'hide_admin_bar_prefs');
function hide_admin_bar_prefs() {

?>
<style type="text/css">
    .show-admin-bar { display: none; }
</style>
<?php

}
```